# Use of caller_ get_ posts

Tags: wp-query, get-posts

For what purpose following parameter is used

> `caller_get_posts`

Comment: It's deprecated, it's the same as the new [`ignore_sticky_posts` parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Sticky_Post_Parameters), which when set to true excludes sticky posts from your query.

Comment: @MarkDuncan it does not exclude sticky posts from query. It does show the posts but in their normal order and those are not on the top of other posts.

Answer (score 10):

If `caller_ get_ posts` is set to true (or 1) then Sticky posts will be excluded from being returned first.

Its kind of a way to turn `sticky posts` off in a query.

Answer (score 5):

Notice:

`caller_get_posts` is deprecated since version 3.1!

Use `ignore_sticky_posts` instead.