# something strange is happening to my code

Tags: loop, css, html

This is my index.php (my homepage). It displays two loops. The first one displays the sticky posts and the second displays all of the posts. The `<div id="primary">` that is located after the first loop is not appearing in my code or functions in my css. This is my code:

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="top-homepage">
  <div id="featured">
  <!-- start sticky posts loop -->
    <?php
      $sticky = new WP_Query( array(
        'showposts' => 6,
        'post__in'  => get_option('sticky_posts'),
        'caller_get_posts' => 1 ) 
      );
    while ( $sticky->have_posts() ) : $sticky->the_post(); ?>
      <div class="featured-post">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
          <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'featuredposts' ); ?>
          <h2 class="post-title">
            <?php echo get_the_title(); ?>
          </h2>
        </a>
      </div><!-- end featured-post -->
    <?php endwhile; ?>
      </div><!-- end featured -->
      <div class="clear"></div>
  </div> <!-- end top homepage -- >

<div id="primary">

<!-- Start the Loop. -->
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php $countpost = $n++ ; ?>

<?php 

  if ($countpost % 2 == 0) { ?>

  <div class="left-post">

  <div class="clear"></div>

      <!-- Display the Title as a link to the Post's permalink. -->

      <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

      Its even

  </div>

<?php } else { ?>

<div class="right-post">

   <!-- Display the Title as a link to the Post's permalink. -->

 <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

 Its odd

</div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<?php } ?>


 <!-- Stop The Loop (but note the "else:" - see next line). -->

 <?php endwhile; else: ?>


 <!-- The very first "if" tested to see if there were any Posts to -->
 <!-- display.  This "else" part tells what do if there weren't any. -->
 <p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>


 <!-- REALLY stop The Loop. -->
 <?php endif; ?>

</div><!-- end primary-->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Do anyone know a solution to this problem? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<!-- end top homepage -- >`

That is not a valid comment. I suspect that it has something to do with that. I really hate those typos. Hard to find.

Comment: OMG ! I have been searching since 3 days for the error, and its in the comment after all. Thanks man

Comment: nice catch, you could actually see it in the way SE formats and colors the code but I couldn't figure what is the exact problem there.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
wp_reset_postdata()
```

after where the first `WP_Query()` ended (assuming, after the first `endwhile;`). It'll reset the first loop, and will give you a fresh loop (whether the default or a new one) after then.

» **Codex: [`wp_reset_postdata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata)**

---

#### EDIT

I think the `caller_get_posts` is guilty. Because it's deprecated since WP v.3.1. Use `ignore_sticky_posts` instead.

> `ignore_sticky_posts` (boolean) - ignore sticky posts or not (available with [Version 3.1](http://codex.wordpress.org/Version_3.1), replaced `caller_get_posts` parameter). Default value is 0 - don't ignore sticky posts. Note: ignore/exclude sticky posts being included at the beginning of posts returned, but the sticky post will still be returned in the natural order of that list of posts returned. ([Source](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters))

So, when you are using:

```
'caller_get_posts' => 1
```

you are actually saying:

```
'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1 //means IGNORE all the sticky posts
```

[This WPSE thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43024/use-of-caller-get-posts) can shed some light on this matter.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried it, but didn't seem to fix the error. I tried it in different places after the endwhile after the ending </div> nothing seems to work

Comment: Ok. Though it won't fix your problem let it be. don't delete it, you need it (See [`WP_Query()` usage](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Usage)). I'm digging it again for any further clue.

Comment: Ok. ferenyl pointed you to the right direction, but consider my one also side by side. It'll assist you get off from deprecated functions or values. (made a new edit)