# How to call custom posts

Tags: custom-post-types

I have this custom post:

```
add_action('init', 'eveniment_register');

function eveniment_register() {
    $args = array(
        'label' => __('Evenimente'),
        'singular_label' => __('Eveniment'),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
        'taxonomies'    => array('category','post_tag','post_thumbnail')

    );

    register_post_type( 'eveniment' , $args );
}
```

And all those custom-posts have a category with `ID=5.`

In `category-5.php` I want to show all custom posts from that category.

How I did it with normal posts with:

```
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

doesn't work with custom posts.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't change the main query. You can simply achieve what you want by using [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts).Fall back to the default loop in category-5.php and add the following to your functions.php

```
function include_category_cpt( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_category( '5' ) && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', 'eveniment' );
        $query->set( 'post_status', 'publish' );
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '-1' );
        $query->set( 'ignore_sticky_posts', '1' );

    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'include_category_cpt' );
```

Also, please note, `caller_get_posts` has long time been depreciated and as replaced with `posts_per_page`

References

- [`is_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category)
- [When to use a custom query and when to use the main query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it like that:

```
<?php
$type = 'eveniment';
$args=array(
  'post_type' => $type,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'caller_get_posts'=> 1);

$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
    <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
    <?php
  endwhile;
}
wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
?>
```

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43024/use-of-caller-get-posts

Comment: Don't do that. See my answer