# Combine "category search order" with "don't display child posts"

Tags: categories

Each of these bits of code work separately in category.php, but when I use both together, the first one is ignored. Can someone tell me how to combine them into a single piece of code, or at least make them play nicely together?

```
<?php if (is_category())
{ $posts = query_posts( $query_string . '&orderby=title&order=asc&posts_per_page=18' );
} ?>

<?php $current_cat = intval( get_query_var('cat') );
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args=array(
'category__and' => array($current_cat),
'paged' => $paged,
'post_type' => 'post',
'caller_get_posts'=> 1
);
query_posts($args);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated, you should never use [`query_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) as it breaks the main query and many functionalities that other code and plugins rely on

> **Note:** This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes. As explained later, there are better, more performant options to alter the main query. query_posts() is overly simplistic and problematic way to modify main query of a page by replacing it with new instance of the query. It is inefficient (re-runs SQL queries) and will outright fail in some circumstances (especially often when dealing with posts pagination).

Also, you should never replace the main query with a custom one. This raises more issues that solving the one you have tried to solve in the first place. Read [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545) on this issue

This all being said, you are going to make use of `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query to change the order of posts to be sorted by title. Then you are going to use `parse_tax_query` to remove the child categories from the category pages

You can do something like in your functions.php

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q )
{
    if (   ! is_admin() 
        && $q->is_main_query()
        && $q->is_category()
    ) {
        /*
         * Set the order so that posts are ordered by post title
         */
        $q->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
        $q->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
        /*
         * Ignore sticky posts, this is the correct syntax to use
         */
        $q->set( 'ignore_sticky_posts', true );

        /*
         * Filter the tax query to remove child categories from category pages
         */
        add_filter( 'parse_tax_query', function ( $q ) 
        {    
            if ( $q->is_main_query()
            ) {
                $q->tax_query->queries[0]['include_children'] = 0;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Also, as already pointed out, `caller_get_posts` is depreciated and is replaced by `ignore_sticky_posts`.

Lastly, your `category.php` should look something like this

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();

        // Your HTML Mark up and template tags etc

    }
}
```

Comment: My pleasure. Enjoy :-)

Answer (score 1):

[Don't use `query_posts()` ;)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts/50762#50762).

In short `query_posts()` over-rides the global `$wp_query`. So subsequent calls replace previous ones. Instead you should use `pre_get_posts`:

```
function wpse183914_filter_child_cats_and_order( $query ) {

    //Alter front-end main query for categories only.
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_category() && !is_admin() ) {
        $cat_id = $query->get_queried_object_id();
        $child_cats = (array) get_term_children( $cat_id, 'category' );

        //exclude the posts in child categories
        $query->set( 'category__not_in', $child_cats );

        //Set sort order
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'asc' );

        //Exclude sticky (see remark at bottom)
        $query->set( 'ignore_sticky_posts', true );
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse183914_filter_child_cats_and_order' );
```

(As an aside [`caller_get_posts` is deprecated](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43024/use-of-caller-get-posts)).

Comment: Thank you for responding, but that doesn't work at all. It's not alphabetized and child posts are displaying.

I took out && !is_admin() and no change.

Comment: Can you confirm that it passes the conditional? If no, which one is failing?